# Unhandled Exception in Visual-C++ for an OpenCV hello world program

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv

I have recently setup openCV 2.3.1 in Visual Studio 2010. I set it up using cmake and managed to run simple 'hello world' code as follows:

```
            #include "stdafx.h"

            #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
            #include <cxcore.h>
            #include <highgui.h>

            int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
            {
                 IplImage *img = cvLoadImage("funny-pictures-cat-goes-pew.jpg");
                 cvNamedWindow("Image:",1);
                 cvShowImage("Image:",img);

                 cvWaitKey();
                 cvDestroyWindow("Image:");
                 cvReleaseImage(&img);

                 return 0;
             }
```

This code was able to run for the first time, though it was displaying a grey image instead of the cat. As I was trying to see whts wrong, it started giving the following error; **Unhandled Exception** at a certain memory location...:![enter image description here][1](can't upload image because of low reputation points. But I hope you understood my problem description...

Regards,
Ruzzar

Comment: Did you run the code in debug mode? Did the image load properly in the first place? You should check the img object if the variables are properly set.

Comment: I have always ran the code in debug mode (even now), it showed a window with a grey colour background, there was no picture there. From there it started  giving the exception errors, and can't anything further...

Comment: Ok, now i've removed the header file opencv2/opencv.hpp with cv.h. And it is not giving the exception error anymore, but it is till displaying a window with a grey background (still, no picture there)...

Comment: Your image is not loading properly. Add a check after cvLoadImage to see if img is not NULL. If it is NULL, most likely - your image is in a different path from where you are running. Try adding the absolute path in cvLoadImage instead of just the image name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please recheck that the *img is being properly filled out?

I just tested this, with the single change that my path to the image is absolute (`IplImage *img = cvLoadImage("D:\\Development\\TestProjects\\OpenCVTest\\funny-pictures-cat-goes-pew.jpg");`), aside from that its the same. It worked perfectly fine on my system here.

OpenCV 2.4.2 used, image from 
http://i288.photobucket.com/albums/ll169/critterclaw101/funny/funny-pictures-cat-goes-pew.jpg

Edit: when testing with a wrongly set path, I get a grey image, thus I am sure that your code cannot find the image.